# What is it called when 2 players make a full run around a table in table tennis?

Tags: trivia, terminology, table-tennis

In modern table tennis it is a common practice to acting the fool when the match is almost over. I.e. players used to flip the side and play a little bit awkward analogue of table tennis when you need to hit your own side and not the another one.

Here is a couple examples what I'm talking about.

- [World Tour Grand Finals Highlights: Ma Long vs Xu Xin (7:34)](http://youtu.be/wKXVtlGB7mc#t=454)
- [Another example](http://youtu.be/z6h-ygv7Y1w)

Is there a special name for it?

Is it a valid table tennis draw according the rules?

And why actually this trick become so popular?

Maybe there is some story behind it?

Answer (score 1):

This is like playing a mini game but doesn't have a specific name for it. If you observe both videos you will find that this was done in the end of the match. People do this when they have no hope of winning. Though it not very sportive it is still done. Hope your query is cleared!

Answer (score 1):

In Italy it is friendly called **"around the world"**.

Is it possible to be played by 2 or more player.

I believe there are no official rules for this kind of matches/points.

A Particular version if **surviving around the world** where many players (more than 2) starts to play in order one shot each moving to the part of the table of that shot (if there are odd numbers of player thay have to move from one side to the other, otherwise thay can hit from the same part of the table) and who fails is eliminated. The game continues until there are no two players who play a traditional point in the final

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that. "Around the world" have nothing about "need to hit your own side of a table and not the another one"

Comment: In Italy is is common to call "around the world" also this kind of game. There are several possibilities to play **around the world** and this is one of them. Maybe someone knows another name for this spaciality...